# User location with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, ip

I am working on a website application where it is necessary to know the location of a user when he/she posts. What would be the best method, using PHP, to determine where (general location) the user is posting from? I know you can use the user's ip with various services offered, but I am looking for something that works with users using our mobile site as well.

Comment: IP is only a semi-accurate approach, and is not always reliable, as one could be using a proxy.

Answer (score 1):

Most sites use `Accept-Language` request header with `$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']`. If request IP also matches the language, you can be pretty sure it's the right country.

Answer (score 1):

maybe use the browsers inbult geolocation tools? eg:

http://www.digimantra.com/howto/current-location-iphone-safari-firefox-browser/

then just parse the javascript info into your php variables?

Answer (score 0):

There are libraries that you can use to lookup the users location via their IP Address like http://www.geoplugin.com/webservices/php